# Creating a combined ring and wedge polygon buffer around vector points in QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, expression, buffer

I’m used to using QGIS for simple operations, but I’ve not found a solution for this.

I have a few vector point layers containing several hundred points in total. The points relate to a raster layer (I can’t post the raster publicly here).

For each vector point, I need to gather data on the raster values from around it, grouped by direction (in 22.5 degree wedges) and distance from the vector point (in 10 regularly-spaced bands). My standard method to gather data around vector points from rasters is to create vector polygons around the point using the Rectangles Oval Diamonds or a buffer tool, and then use Raster Statistics for Polygons or Zonal Statistics to gather the relevant data within the polygon area from the raster.

My issue is trying to create a polygon layer around each point which incorporates both the ring and wedge form, like this one:

[image]

I’ve tried the various buffer and shape creation tools that I’m aware of, but none create a polygon layer of this complexity (there are, in practice, 160 polygons in this layer). I can generate the rings using various tools and plugins, but I haven’t found I way to create multiple wedges or to combine the two into one overlay layer.

I can draw each polygon manually by using ring and wedge tools or by splitting the rings with polygon editing tools, as I have for this example, but because I need to repeat this operation for several hundred vector points, I need to find a way to automate it more.

I’ve found questions relating to various types of buffers on here, but not a solution for one of this form (apologies if I’ve overlooked something). Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create such repeated wedge-buffers using QGIS expressions with [Geoemtry generator or Geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814). The trick is to use [wedge_buffer()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#wedge-buffer) function together with [array_foreach()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?#array-foreach) twice to iterate 1) for each band (increasing distance) and 2) for each angle-segment (increasing angle).

Use this expression on your point-layer (see at the bottom for some details to be aware of). Change `100` (three times on lines 14 and 15) for the distance of the regularly spaced bands and on line 9, chang `(0,9)` for the number of rings you want to get, here:10 (0 to 9):

```
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (0,15),
        with_variable (
            'azim',
            @element,
            collect_geometries (
                array_foreach (
                    generate_series (0,9),
                    wedge_buffer( 
                        $geometry, 
                        @azim*22.5+(22.5/2), 
                        22.5,
                        @element*100,
                        100+@element*100
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

*The expression in action, here with Geoemtry generator and transparent color to show that there are no overlapping polygons:*
[image]

**Things to be aware of:**

- Using [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#geometry-by-expression), output will be one multipart geometry. Use [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#multipart-to-singleparts) to get individual features.
- When working with angles, be sure to use an appropriate CRS: one that preserves angles like Mercator projection.
- Also be aware of distance distortion of the CRS you select if your area of interest does cover larger areas.